# Ever since update, disk added to computer

Tags: windows-10, storage, windows-10-v1803

Ever since I recently updated Windows 10 (v1803), a new "Local Disk" appeared (F):
[image: Devices and Drives]

When I open it, it's empty. These are the properties:
[image: Properties]

Then, every few minutes it seems, even if I keep clearing the notification, this pops up:

[image: Notification]

Which is, needless to say, annoying.

What could be causing this? How do I stop it?

Edit: Hidden files is enabled
[image]

Comment: Do you have "show hidden files" enabled for that drive? If not, do so, and see what may be on it.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Yes, already had that enabled.

Comment: Do you have any USB storage connected? If so, does it have indicator lights showing activity when you try to access F:?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin looks like it's a bug with the update? Anyways, the duplicate answered my question. Thanks